# Angular redirect page if HTTP response is 401

Tags: angular

I'm sending multiple API requests in my Angular (10) app. If one of the requests returns response with status 401 I would like to redirect the page to my login page (from the component page).

I have a service that responsible for API calls that has the following 2 methods :

```
    export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
}
      public get<T>(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams(), headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()): Observable<T> {
        return this.getBodyOfResponseOrRedirect(
          this.http.get<T>(path, {headers, params, observe: 'response'}));
      }
    
      private getBodyOfResponseOrRedirect<T>(responseObservable: Observable<HttpResponse<T>>): Observable<T> {
        return responseObservable.pipe(map(response => {
          if (response.status === 401) {
            window.location.href = 'https://custom-url';
          } else {
            return response.body;
          }
        }));
      }
```

Now I tried using the API service methods in another service:

```
 export class ShopDataService{
  ...
  getShopsData(): Observable<Shop[]> {
    return this.apiService.get<Shop[]>("https://shops.com/v1/endpoint)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('shop recieved : ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    errorMessage = `Server returned code : ${err.status}, error message is : ${err.message}`;
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

The redirect doesn't work when the response status is 401, instead I'm seeing in the console :

> main.gb7558h03a743440f512.js:1 Server returned code : 401, error message is : Http failure response for https://shops.com/v1/endpoint: 401 OK

What am I doing wrong ?

The big idea here, is that when I load the component my auth token is valid. After some time, my token is expired but I didn't refresh or move to another page. Therefore, current page functionality might send api requests with an invalid token and will get 401 error in response. I would like to handle this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 401 Unauthorized response is usually emitted as an `error` notification from the Angular `HttpClient`. So you'd need to use RxJS [`catchError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) operator to catch the error and redirect. You could then emit [`NEVER`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/NEVER) constant so that nothing emits after the redirect and keep the observable alive, or emit [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant to complete the observable.

Try the following

```js
import { throwError, NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  public get<T>(
    path: string, 
    params: HttpParams = new HttpParams(), 
    headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
  ): Observable<T> {
    return this.getBodyOfResponseOrRedirect(
      this.http.get<T>(path, {headers, params, observe: 'response'}));
  }

  private getBodyOfResponseOrRedirect<T>(
    responseObservable: Observable<HttpResponse<T>>
  ): Observable<T> {
    return responseObservable.pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (!!error.status && error.status === 401) {
          window.location.href = 'https://custom-url';
          return NEVER;            // <-- never emit after the redirect
        }
        return throwError(error);  // <-- pass on the error if it isn't 401
      }),
      map(response =>  response.body)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll run it now and update :) Tnx for the quick answer. Do you think that the way I handle this problem is the right way ? or maybe is there a different way which is better ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in catching and redirecting in the `catchError` block.

Comment: I feel like this type of solution is dirty. It means that in every api request that you send, u might be redirected to a login page (if 401 returned). Feels like there might be a better way to handle it, maybe using the catchError in the places that call apiService but then it means duplicate code of catchError

Comment: More elegant way would be to use an Interceptor. But that would also mean checking every HTTP request made.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael D solution was super helpfull. Based on his comment I implemented the following  http interceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (!!error.status && error.status === 401) {
        window.location.href = 'url';
        return NEVER;
      }
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }

}
```